# Authentication: facebook authencation via API

Tags: wcf, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

Can we authenticate to facebook Via API not through User Interface which prompts for credentials?

Since facebook is turning off/removing the Offline_Access permission, Is there any way I can login using App? I am planning to use Facebook C# SDK v 6.0.

In otherwords, how to authenticate as an app by using Facebook C# SDK V 6.

I found this documentation on facebook http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/applications/

I want to use app authentication and then post to pages which has already granted "manage_pages,publish_Stream" permissions to the app by using graph api explorer.

Comment: If you already have a page access token – those do not expire by default – then way not just use that to post to the page?

Comment: I have page access token, but the new facebook changes remove "Offline_Access" permission by Oct 3rd. So I need to get the page access token by using user credentials via API not through UI.

Comment: You can get a page access token via API, if the current app user has given you `manage_pages` permission – then you just have to query `/me/accounts` and pick the right page from there.

Comment: Well, Let me explain the problem I am facing. I am the user and I administer 2 pages other than my page feed. I have created an app and granted the manage_permissions,Publish_stream by using Graph API Explorer at developers.facebook.com and then I want to use a program with out user intervention which can post to the other pages which I administer but not to my page feed. I tried the code by getting application token and try to post these pages by [PAgeID]/Feed and its giving me an OAuth exception - User hasn't authorized to perform this action. How can I do this?

Comment: Again: Get a _page_ access token.

Comment: If Page Access token expires every 60 days like the user access token then I do not want build an app for users. Because our users do not wish to login when they want to post a message to facebook. But every 60 days I do not want to get the new access token on behalf of user as there are 5-7 apps which are posting to these pages. Please let me know if there is an alternative Otherwise I will sorry for users. They have to login and do on their own.